# Pandas dataframe not recognizing multiple if statements

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, indexing

I have a dataframe that looks like the following, with the Hour column as a series of integers:

```
  |Hour| 
 0|23  |
 1|14  |
 2|6   |
 3|2   |
```

My desired output is the following:

```
  |Hour| TimeofDay   |
 0|23  | Late Evening|
 1|14  | Mid Day     |
 2|6   | Morning     |
 3|2   | Morning     |
```

To achieve this result, I'm using the following lines of code:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if row["Hour"] > 16:
        df['TimeofDay'] = "Late Evening"
    elif np.logical_and(row["Hour"] > 8 , row["Hour"] <= 16):
        df['HarshEventTime'] = "Mid Day"
    else :    
        df['HarshEventTime'] = "Morning"
```

Unfortunately my output is the following:

```
  |Hour| TimeofDay   |
 0|23  | Morning     |
 1|14  | Morning     |
 2|6   | Morning     |
 3|2   | Morning     |
```

Is there a reason my if statement isn't reading my conditions correctly?

Comment: For starters, there’s no need to iterate the DataFrame for this.  Broadcasting will be much clearer and more efficient.  `numpy.where` might be helpful, but the first statement can be done natively.

Answer (score 1):

I find it easier to use the .loc function of pandas for if statements, for the output you want the code is as follows:

```
df['TimeofDay'] = "Morning"
df.loc[(df["Hour"] > 8) & (df["Hour"] <= 16), 'TimeofDay'] = "Late Evening"
df.loc[df['Hour'] > 16, 'TimeofDay'] = "Late Evening"
```

You start with your else statement and then apply any conditions that would change that column.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using different columns to write the time of day,

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if row["Hour"] > 16:
        df['TimeofDay'] = "Late Evening" #here 'TimeofDay'
    elif np.logical_and(row["Hour"] > 8 , row["Hour"] <= 16):
        df['HarshEventTime'] = "Mid Day" #here 'HarshEventTime'
    else :    
        df['HarshEventTime'] = "Morning" #here 'HarshEventTime'
```

Try using the same one.

Comment: Iteration is not needed. It’s messy and inefficient.  Perhaps adjust to use broadcasting instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can also consider using numpy select:

```
conditions = [df['Hour'] > 16, df['Hour'] > 8, df['Hour'] <= 8]
choices = ['Late Evening', 'Mid Day', 'Morning']

df['TimeofDay'] = np.select(conditions, choices)
```